# Irreducible polynomial method.

Tags: polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials

I have found a question where I have to determine the irreducibility of a polynomial $f$ in $\textbf{Q}[X]$. Namely,
$$ f=2X^3-X-6.$$

The method used which I do not understand is;

Suppose there is a rational zero , $r=\frac{m}{n}$ where $n$ is bigger than or equal to one,  subbing in for $r$ and multiplying up by $n$ we get ,

$$2m^{3}-mn^2-6n^3,$$ if $p|n$ then from the equation $p|2m^3$. Since $p$ does not divide $m$, we have $p=2$, But then $4|2m^3$. So that $m$ and $n$ are both even; which is a contradiction. Thus $n=1$ and $m^{3}-m-6=0$ Hence $m|6$ and so we need to check the divisors of 6. Which shows it is irreducible over $\textbf{Q}$.

I understand the last bit once we have deduced $2m^{3}-m-6=0$ but it is the part before, please may someone explain this method.

Comment: Which part exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @Sil they have said $p|n$ and $p|2m^3$ i take it this is from $n|m$? and then they go on to say since $p$ doesn't divide $m$, why?

Comment: First, assume $\frac{m}{n}$ is in lowest terms, and choose some prime dividing $n$. The argument then shows that $p=2$ and then that $p\mid m$ as well, so that $m$ and $n$ (*not* $p$ and $n$) are both even, contradicting the lowest terms assumption. Does that help?

Comment: The coefficient for $m^3$ is wrong.  It should be $2m^3-m-6=0$

Comment: @rogerl how does the argument show this?

Comment: @GNUSupporter thankyou my mistake.

Comment: would it not be factors of $6n^3$ over factors of $2m^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that a root is $\frac{m}{n}$ where $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then as you show, we get
$$2m^3 - mn^2 - 6n^3 = 0,\text{ so that }2m^3 = mn^2 + 6n^3 = n(mn+6n^2).$$
If $n\ne 1$, choose some prime $p\mid n$. Then $p$ divides the right-hand side above, so $p\mid 2m^3$. Since $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, we must have $p\mid 2$, so that $p = 2$. But then the right-hand side, $n(mn+6n^2)$, consists of two even factors, so is divisible by $4$. Thus $4\mid 2m^3$ and therefore $2\mid m$, a contradiction.

This implies $n=1$, so that (as you point out) we are reduced to looking for integral roots of $2m^3-m-6$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). It shows that the polynomial has no rational root. Since a cubic polynomial over a field is irreducible if and only if it has no root, we are done.

Comment: Thankyou,after reading this theorem i still do not understand the introduction of $p$.

Comment: would it not be factors of $6n^3$ over factors of $2m^3$?

Comment: Since $m$ and $n$ are coprime, $p\mid n$ means $p\nmid m$. Did you try  the Rational Root Theorem for your example?

Comment: Okay now its making sense, why do we get $4|2m^3$?

Comment: In your text, $2=p\mid n$ says that $4\mid n^2$. So from the equation, also $4\mid 2m^3$.

Comment: Why do they decompose into primes etc why cant we just do $\frac{\textrm{factors of }6}{\textrm{factors of }2}$